# Responsive button with triangle

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a vertical menu placed in Bootstrap container, that consists of two types of buttons

- Button with a CSS triangle (placed on :after) at the end (red one)
- Regular buttons placed in

  (green ones)

**Problems:**

1. The typography of the page relies on relative units rem. As the viewport enlarges, also the font-sizes as well as padding inside of the buttons grows. **This cause problems with the triangle size and its position**.
2. All menu items must be aligned with each other on the right. But the triangle of the first button is **placed using negative margin, so it overlaps**.

Here's an example:
http://www.bootply.com/k3dPxTZYTs#

How could these problems be solved?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div> 
      <a href="#" class="btn-switch">
        Lorem Ipsum 

      </a>
    </div>

  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Option A </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Option B </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Option C </li></a>
  </ul>

</div>
```

CSS (full CSS involving responsive typography can be found in the BootPly example):

```
.btn-switch {
  background: #f00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #A00;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-switch:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 1.4rem 0px 1.4rem 1.4rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -1.4rem;
  margin-top: -1.4rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
li {
  background: #0f0;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recomend you use box-sizin

```
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

than you can make use of CSS calc, where you can calculate the length of an element mixing percentage with other units, in your case would be between percentage and rem

The code would be... hope this helps you

```
.btn-switch {
  background: #f00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #A00;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 1.4rem);
}

.btn-switch:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 1.4rem 0px 1.4rem 1.4rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1.4rem;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/griiettner/pen/beviH)